# Vuetify v-select onchange event returns previously selected value instead of current

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `<v-select>` dropdown that I'm wanting to use as a list of URLs to navigate to other pages. The issue I'm running into is the `onchange`event I'm using returns the previously selected value instead of the current selected value.

I have tweaked the code to print to console instead for testing. The `:hint` functionality works fine so I'm sure it's something to do with the `onchange` function.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PebrqW?editors=1011)

Here's the code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6>
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          v-model="select"
          label="Select"
          single-line
          item-text="report"
          item-value="src"
          return-object
          persistent-hint
          v-on:change="changeRoute(`${select.src}`)"
          :hint="`${select.src}`"
        ></v-select>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable */
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
      return {
        select: { report: 'Rep1', src: '/rep1' },
        items: [
          { report: 'Rep1', src: '/rep1' },
          { report: 'Rep2', src: '/rep2' }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      changeRoute(a) {
        //this.$router.push({path: a })
        console.log(a)
      }
    }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need to specify the data because that's what, I'm guessing, the change event passes by default.

So change:

```
v-on:change="changeRoute(`${select.src}`)"
```

to just

```
v-on:change="changeRoute"
```

and in the function call:

```
  changeRoute(a) {
    this.$router.push({path: a.src })
    console.log(a)
  }
```

Comment: i'm using v-select in a v-data-table, as it only provides the new value to the change handler, how am i supposed to know what item this is for ?

Answer (score 17):

I have no idea why `change` doesn't work properly. But `input` does work.

https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/erBwKa?editors=1011

```
v-on:input="changeRoute(`${select.src}`)"
```

Perhaps you can [open a new bug report for Vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues)

Comment: I think it's not a bug tho. It's just that on `change` you pass an argument when the change is triggered, but not yet updated, so argument is still the old value. `input` gets triggered only after value is updated, thus it works.

Comment: @Traxo but even when i use `this.select.src` in the change event handler, it returns the old value. that's why i think it's a bug.

Comment: Also incorrect because then you must use `$nextTick`

Comment: @Traxo there is no proper reason that `$nextTick` should be required. that's for DOM update. `this.select.src` should be changed instantaneously. when i change the code to normal select, `change` works https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/aGpzmm?editors=1111. in vuetify, it does not work https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PebrqW?editors=1011 . it works for normal select but not for vuetify select, still not a bug ?

Comment: Hmm I might be wrong, but I think you can't compare it like that because vuetify uses it's own custom select component, thus events might not be same.

Answer (score 17):

For vue3 the event for v-select is `update:modelValue`

```js
@update:modelValue="changeRoute"
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't exctly know why ${select.src} is holding previous value on change event.
You can give a try with below code:

```
<v-select @change="changeRoute" ></v-select>

methods: {
      changeRoute(selectObj) {
        console.log(selectObj)
        console.log(selectObj.src)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@input="changeRoute(select.src)"
```